# Implement the delegates for receiving push notification actions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I've created a push local notification for my alarm project.

The problem is that when I click an action button (snooze and okay) the delegates that I implemented doesn't get called.

Here is my code for push local notification:

```
UIMutableUserNotificationAction *notificationAction1 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
notificationAction1.identifier = Snooze;
notificationAction1.title = @"Snooze";
notificationAction1.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
notificationAction1.destructive = NO;
notificationAction1.authenticationRequired = NO;

UIMutableUserNotificationAction *notificationAction2 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
notificationAction2.identifier = Okay;
notificationAction2.title = @"Okay";
notificationAction2.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
notificationAction2.destructive = NO;
notificationAction2.authenticationRequired = NO;

UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *notificationCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
notificationCategory.identifier = @"Alarm";
[notificationCategory setActions:@[notificationAction1,notificationAction2] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];
[notificationCategory setActions:@[notificationAction1,notificationAction2] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextMinimal];

NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects:notificationCategory, nil];
```

Here is the code for implementing the delegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler {    
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:Snooze]) {

        NSLog(@"You chose Snooze");
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:Okay]) {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
        NSLog(@"You chose Okay");
    }
    if (completionHandler) {

        completionHandler();
    }
}
```

I don't know yet how to make the snooze and okay button to work so I just log something but nothing is being log when I click snooze/okay. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code, It may help you..

```
NSString * const NotificationCategoryIdent  = @"ACTIONABLE";
NSString * const NotificationActionOneIdent = @"ACTION_ONE";
NSString * const NotificationActionTwoIdent = @"ACTION_TWO";

- (void)registerForNotification {

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action1;
    action1 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [action1 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
    [action1 setTitle:@"Action 1"];
    [action1 setIdentifier:NotificationActionOneIdent];
    [action1 setDestructive:NO];
    [action1 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action2;
    action2 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [action2 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
    [action2 setTitle:@"Action 2"];
    [action2 setIdentifier:NotificationActionTwoIdent];
    [action2 setDestructive:NO];
    [action2 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actionCategory;
    actionCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
    [actionCategory setIdentifier:NotificationCategoryIdent];
    [actionCategory setActions:@[action1, action2] 
                    forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

    NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:actionCategory];
    UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|
                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound|
                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);

    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings;
    settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types
                                                 categories:categories];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}
```

There are 2 new methods on the UIApplicationDelegate protocol.

```
1) application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:
2) application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:completionHandler:
```

These methods will get called, in the background, when the user selects an action from your push notification.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:NotificationActionOneIdent]) {

        NSLog(@"You chose action 1.");
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:NotificationActionTwoIdent]) {   

        NSLog(@"You chose action 2.");
    }    
    if (completionHandler) {

        completionHandler();
    }
}
```

[Source Link](https://nrj.io/simple-interactive-notifications-in-ios-8/)

Comment: I followed the steps ,no error, and running but still doesn't log when the action button is clicked.